# Google App Engine upgrade error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was trying to upgrade to 1.5.4 and I downloaded the new version from the download page and now when I click the browse button on the Launcher I get and ascii error. Does anyone know what is going on?

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4143, in  _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files  (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4049, in  _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 616, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3120, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3024, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2882, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    handler_path, cgi_path, import_hook)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2747, in LoadTargetModule
    raise SyntaxError(error)
SyntaxError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) please see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (ting.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the code path for loading the `script:` file specified in `app.yaml`. It expects to find 7-bit clean ascii, but is finding something else.

Any chance that the python script specified by `script:` (which appears to be `ting.py`) got garbled?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have 2 scripts in there. I removed the first one from app.yaml and run the installer again with repair option but I got the same error. Now I am trying with the other one. Does this mean there is non-ascii character inside one of these scripts? Thanks again.

Comment: If you're getting the same error, then yes. I edited my answer to note that the script was ting.py. Whatever is in parenthesis at the end of that stack trace is the file that's problematic. Rather than just removing it, I'd open it in a text editor to make sure it's O.K. If it is, there's some deeper problem.

Comment: Now I got this error: `Not found error: / did not match any patterns in application configuration.` I am now trying with an old version of the script.

Comment: Hi, there must be something wrong with the way my text editor saves the files. I copied the ting.py to Notepad and saved it as text and ran the repair again. This time worked. But all data in datastore in SDK is gone. What do you advise? What will happen when I upload the app? Will I also lose data in the production server? And what is _AhAdminXsrfToken that I see in Entity Kind pull down in SDK? Not sure if it was there before? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Zeynel: it's incredibly unlikely you could write a script with non-ASCII characters that would actually be interpreted in a way that would delete data from the datastore. However, you should almost certainly start using a real text editor instead of whatever you're using.

Comment: Losing dev data between SDK installs is normal. The dev datastore is a simulation of the real thing, and we periodically tweak it. That has nothing to do with production data. The XsrfToken is new, and is about protecting against XSRF exploits.

Comment: @Wooble, I am using EditPad Pro, I think that's a good text editor. But now I realized that it was saving my python scripts as `Batch file output()` now I am trying to find out if this is the cause of the problem. I asked a question at superuser http://superuser.com/questions/337944/editpad-pro-saves-python-files-as-batch-file-output. Thanks

Comment: @Dave Smith: Thanks for the help. I am still trying to find out what's wrong with my text editor. I am also using Python 2.6.1 and I see that the log file contains a warning about using a more recent version than 2.5. Can this be related to the problem that I am having?

Comment: You're fine with Python 2.6.1 unless you use any features or libraries that are newer than 2.5.